# html viewport in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css, viewport

kindly check on this website in an iPhone or iTouch:

http://www.imageworkz.asia/sixsenses

As u can see, the website appears to be "halved".

I am currently using this meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This doesn't seem to fix the problem. I am completely clueless to what I should do to fix this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try `initial-scale=1.0` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

Comment: umm. it kinda made it even worse for both iPAD and the iPhone.

Comment: Will it? According to Apple’s documentation, that just makes Safari run in full-screen mode when the website loads: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html